# Measuring income inequality using the R survey package

Tags: r, survey, inequality, gini

I'm working with American Community Survey microdata using the `survey` package, and am hoping to calculate some basic income inequality statistics. I've set up the following as my design:

```
testsurv <- svrepdesign(data=test, repweights = test[,8:87], weights = test$HHWT, 
                   combined.weights=TRUE, type = "Fay", rho = 0.5,scale=4/80, 
                   rscales = rep(1, 80), mse=TRUE)
```

From that, I'd like to calculate gini coefficients by year, as well as quantile ratios of income, also by year. Generating the quantiles and the related errors is straightforward using `svyby` and `svyquantile`:

```
quants <- svyby(~INCOME, ~YEAR, testsurvey, svyquantile, 
              quantiles=c(0.9, 0.75, 0.5, 0.25, 0.1), keep.var=TRUE)
```

That brings me to my first question: How do I calculate the the standard errors for ratios of income quantiles (e.g. 90/10) if I have the replicate-weight-based errors for each quantile? I tried using `svyratio` but that's for the ratios of entire variables, not for selected observations within variables.

Second question: Is there a way to calculate the gini coefficient (with replicate-based errors) within `survey` using existing functions like `gini` from `reldist`? I tried using `withReplicates` but it didn't work well, maybe because `gini` orders its arguments as variable, then weights, but the instructions for `withReplicates` specify the opposite order. I tried both ways but neither worked. For example, this, where HHWT is the sample weights:

```
> withReplicates(testsurv, gini(~HHWT, ~INCOME))
```

That yields the following error message:

```
Error in sum(weights) : invalid 'type' (language) of argument
In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'language'
```

Answer (score 3):

use the R convey package.  this is not yet available on CRAN but you can install it quickly with

```
devtools::install_github("djalmapessoa/convey")
```

for the ratio of 90th to 10th, use the `?svyqsr` function and set `alpha=` to `0.1` because it defaults to 80th and 20th

for the gini coefficient, use the `?svygini` function

these should both be straightforward computations so long as you have the acs replicate-weighted survey design.  be sure to use the `convey_prep` function immediately after the `svrepdesign` call!

Comment: Thanks Anthony - I look forward to trying it out (and thank you also for your great website, which is a great resource)!

Comment: it is on CRAN now

Comment: Anthony - this is a ridiculously late response, but I wanted to thank you for the pointer to this fantastic package. It's a great contribution and has been indispensable for my project.